# Select and filter duplicate base on 2 column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that is connected to a large datasource  csv file, I really do not like this query am using  and the DISTINCT I used is really filtering out some date and time column .  The Index Num. should be distinct with the HC Serial code , Date and time format. The output should be like this

```
  SELECT        DISTINCT [Index Num#], [HC SERIAL CODE], MIN(Format([Date time], 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS Startdate, MIN(Format([Date time], 'HH:mm')) AS Starttime
FROM            combinedKPI.csv
WHERE        Format([Date time], 'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN DATE () AND DATE () - 111
GROUP BY [Index Num#], [HC SERIAL CODE],Format([Date time], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
ORDER BY [HC SERIAL CODE], Format([Date time], 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

[image]

Output should be like this

```
HC Serial Code   Index Num.      Start Date     Start time
    xx072               1        15/06/2018     17:29
    xx072               1        03/07/2018     17:02
    1401                1        12/12/2016     06:00
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as it it difficult to fathom what you are asking

Comment: Why does the day portion of the second row in the expected result read "15/06/2018" and not "03/07/2018"?

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text.

Comment: Add your used DBMS

Comment: @sticky bit. I have edited it. it is my error. It is image attached and until you click it you can not see.

Comment: And why don't you want to use `SELECT DISTINCT ...`, if I got that right?

Comment: I used it, but still omitting some dates and time.

Comment: Possibly show the query with `DISTINCT` and elaborate exactly what was missing with it.

Comment: Check ! I have edited my post to update the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` and `min()` are the cause, that certain times are not shown. Just use `DISINCT` and leave the `GROUP BY` and `min()`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       [hc serial code]
       [index num#],
       format([date time], 'yyyy-MM-dd') startdate,
       format([date time], 'HH:mm') starttime
       FROM combinedKPI.csv
       WHERE Format([date time], 'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN date()
                                               AND date() - 111
       ORDER BY [hc serial code],
                format([date time], 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need `DISTINCT` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT [HC SERIAL CODE], [Index Num#], 
       CAST([Date time] AS Date) AS StartDate, CAST([Date time] AS TIME(0)) AS Starttime
FROM combinedKPI.csv 
WHERE CAST([Date time] AS Date) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS Date) AND
      CAST([Date time] AS Date) <= DATEADD(DAY, -111, GETDATE());
```